# copyToLocal: No such file or directory

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to copy a file from hadoop hdfs to local with the following command:

```
bin/hadoop fs -copyToLocal /user/nj/dir/hfile file:///home/nj/lfile
copyToLocal
```

and getting

> No such file or directory

However, `ls` works, and I am able to read the file contents using `cat`. Tried get and sudo option but same error.

Comment: instead of this file:///home/nj/lfile try giving your localfile system path like ~/nj/lfile

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you want to copy the **hfile** to data folder in **nj** user's home directory . Then use the following command .

```
bin/hdfs dfs -copyToLocal /user/nj/dir/hfile /home/nj/data/
```

or

```
bin/hdfs dfs -copyToLocal /user/nj/dir/hfile /home/nj/data/lfile
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs because of there is no home directory created on HDFS for your current user.
the solution is simple; look here:
[https://tecadmin.net/hadoop-hdfs-ls-no-such-file-or-directory.](https://tecadmin.net/hadoop-hdfs-ls-no-such-file-or-directory/)